# How to interpret this problem question?

Tags: self-study, linear-model

My course problem booklet (mathematics BSc, second-year module in statistical inference and modelling, unpublished) has a question,

> A runner completes two laps of a course. He is timed over each lap and over both laps together. The recorded times, which are unbiased and equally reliable, are 52, 55 and 108 seconds. Write down a linear model in matrix notation to represent these data, and hence obtain the least squares estimate of the lap times.

I think I see two assumptions here, both of which strike me as a bit odd.

Assumption 1: lap 1 and lap 2 are distinct and independent entities, despite being run over the same course.

Assumption 2: there is a 'true lap time' for each lap that is invariant between trials and can be estimated by realisations.

Am I right?

Comment: Well, there is a true lap time, it's the time that the runner actually ran the lap in.  What is measured is the true lap time + some measurement error.  WRT Assumption 1; it's not that the laps are independent, its that the random component of the measurement - i.e., the measurement error - is independent from lap to lap.

Comment: @jbowman If the laps aren't independent, why represent them by different parameters, to be estimated? By 'true lap time' I mean "the time in which the runner, in principle, runs a lap, from which actually-run laps may deviate by some margin"; isn't that what the question tries to estimate?

Comment: The lap times are whatever they were.  The question concerns *estimates* of the lap times based on *measurements* that are *subject to error.*

Comment: @whuber I got an estimate of $52.3$s for lap 1 and $55.3$s for lap 2, which agrees with the solution booklet. Does that mean that the model suggests $0.3$s of measurement error in the given times?

Comment: That sounds about right, assuming your values are all rounded to one decimal place.

Comment: @whuber Suppose the runner had run one lap in 10s and another in 20s. By this reasoning, should we conclude that he probably ran the lap in 15s both times, and we got 5s of measurement error in different directions each time? Doesn't that leave out the plausibility of variation in the true run time?

Comment: That's incorporated within the question: it does not ask you to assume both laps were run in the same time.  That's how you can obtain two different estimates for the two times!  If you have *only* a 10s measurement of one lap and a 20s measurement of the other, then this model will estimate that the true times are 10 and 20s, respectively, and were measured without error.